# Fixed seed random number between 0 and 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want to generate list of fixed random numbers by giving a seed between 0 and 1 in python. For example, l = [0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0.75]. I can get this by using random.random(). But every time it gives a new random number list. I want to fix it by giving some some seed.

How can I do that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: [`random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
import random
l = []
n = 10      # you can change it to whatever you want, it is list length
for i in range(n):
    random.seed(i)
    l += [random.random()]

print(l)
```

it will always give same random list.

Comment: This is overly complicated for what he needs: You don't have to generate a new seed for every call to `random.random`. Calling `random.seed(0)`, or any specific number, before the loop, would work just fine. Also, `l.append(random.random())` would be the preferred way in my opinion to build that list

Comment: Thanks @ands i wanted the list this way but @TemporalWolf was also right `random.seed(i)` should be before the loop.

Comment: yes @TemporalWolf is right you can just put  `random.seed(0)` before loop, also than you can use just  `l = [random.random() for i in range(n)]`.

Answer (score 4):

Check out pydocs page for [random.seed()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed)

```
[>>> seed = 123
[>>> random.seed(seed)
[>>> i = [random.random() for _ in xrange(5)]
[>>> print i
[0.052363598850944326, 0.08718667752263232, 0.4072417636703983, 0.10770023493843905, 0.9011988779516946]
```

Calling the above will return the same list each time.  In other words, the output is deterministic and predictable.

Note that Python 3 users have to use `[random.random() for _ in range(5)]`.

Comment: This is the solution I would have written. set a single, specific seed. Bonus for using `for _ in xrange()`.